# How to fix double href in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Following a tutorial I set up routes for a webapp written in PHP. Everything works until certain point. For instance, when I click a link from the base it takes me to the desired page e.g. `about/culture`. But when inside culture page I got `about/about/culture` or `about/about` links what is wrong because these routes don't exist. I pretty new on this, How I can fix it up?

My .htaccess file is this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /PHP/20-DI_Container/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL

Comment: You should _start_ by making it clear to yourself how resolving of relative URLs by the client actually works.